# Does Firefox support SVG getIntersectionList? Docs & Tests disagree

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, mozilla

I'm looking for a simply point in polygon test for a large number of SVG paths in javascript. getIntersectionList seems to be the right function - but everywhere I look I see discussion over the last 10 years that says it is not supported in mozilla/firefox, including the mozilla.org docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_1.1_Support_in_Firefox

However I found example code that seems to work correctly and support getIntersectionList:

[http://dahlström.net/svg/interactivity/intersection/sandbox_hover.svg](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/intersection/sandbox_hover.svg)

```
var list = root.getIntersectionList(rpos, null);
// Works
```

And by contrast another example that fails and says the same function is unsupported:

https://codepen.io/team/articulate/pen/HIFyi

```
input.value = svg.getIntersectionList(irect, null).length
// Uncaught TypeError: svg.getIntersectionList is not a function
```

I want to get this working in all modern browsers - so it is weird that mozilla seems to say it is unsupported when it does sometimes work in practice. Is there any updated docs from mozilla to say it has been added?

Comment: It does not, no. You checked Erik's code in a debugger did you? Because it sure looks like it fails when that method is called.

Comment: Happy to review a patch if you want to implement it in gecko.

Comment: Thanks Robert, sanity restored. Answered the question below.

Answer (score 0):

No. As Robert Longson comments the first svg example also fails getIntersectionList
and Firefox does not support it.

Fails on the first example:
[http://dahlström.net/svg/interactivity/intersection/sandbox_hover.svg](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/intersection/sandbox_hover.svg)

I was confused because the demo app reported the correct path that the mouse was over - but this was down to processing a mousemove event, not due to getIntersectionList.

I had only read the code around getIntersectionList... and not used the debugger.

Still a bit weird - in that the mousemove event has a perfectly good point in SVG hittest, but I can't access the same test with a coordinate. Looks like I'll need to roll my own collision testing for SVG polygons.